# How to change some text in a form using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I need to change the text in a form "Search Listings By Type:" (translation in spanish "Buscar Listado por Categoria")

```
<form action="" id="searchform" method="get" role="search">
    <input type="hidden" name="s" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="listing">
    <select style="float:left;" class="wp-listings-taxonomy custom_search" id="status" name="status">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Search Listings By Type:</option>
        <option value="features">Featured</option>
        <option value="new">New</option>
        <option value="for-sale">For Sale</option>
        <option value="for-rent">For Rent</option>
    </select>
    <div class="btn-search">
        <button class="searchsubmit custom_button" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            <span class="button-text">Search Listings</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

I am thinking it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#searchform option:selected" ).val("").text("Buscar Listado por Categoria");
});
```

To set the text? This is not working so it is obvius I am missing something. How to do this properly?

Comment: Don't you have access to the HTML file? You can edit it in there anytime.

Comment: No I do not. That is why I need Jquery. It is buried in a PHP file that I cant find and if I did, it  would be overwritten on the next update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```js
$("#status option:first" ).text("Buscar Listado por Categoria");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="searchform" method="get" role="search">
    <input type="hidden" name="s" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="listing">
    <select style="float:left;" class="wp-listings-taxonomy custom_search" id="status" name="status">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Search Listings By Type:</option>
        <option value="features">Featured</option>
        <option value="new">New</option>
        <option value="for-sale">For Sale</option>
        <option value="for-rent">For Rent</option>
    </select>
    <div class="btn-search">
        <button class="searchsubmit custom_button" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            <span class="button-text">Search Listings</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('#status option').eq(0).text('Buscar Listado por Categoria');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/56ha33h2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:contains` to find the element by his content:

```
$(function(){
    $("option:contains('Search Listings By Type:')").text("Buscar Listado por Categoria")
})
```

See the [**:contains() Selector documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Comment: Madeiros. I forgot about those types of selectors. Thank!